# how can i select from a mysql table where column value is greater than some value if the column is text and numbers

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called "products" where one column is "SerialNumber". The problem is that this column is text latin1_swedish_ci and values are like "BC00001, BC0002, etc. i need to select all products where serial number is for example greater than some given serial number.
i tried selecting like this:

```
SELECT * FROM 'products' WHERE 'SerialNumber' >= 'BC00563'
```

But since this column is text, it' not working.
I can't modify the table structure because the this table laready has 20.000 + records.
Any help appreciated!

Comment: Is the field always in the same format of two letters then numbers?

Comment: Other than `'` what's wrong with your solution?

Comment: `SELECT 'BC00564' > 'BC00563'; -> 1`

Comment: Oh, and 20000 rows is no reason at all for not modifying structure where it's necessary or appropriate to do so.

Comment: Presumably BC02 is 'larger' than BC001 ?

Comment: first of all. thanks. @strawberry good point but it is not only the table to modify. it would be necessary to modify a whole bunch of code and ohter tables too.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the value is always two characters followed by numbers, you can strip out the characters and convert the remaining values into `number` for the comparison, e.g.:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `products` 
WHERE `SerialNumber` >= 
    CASE WHEN 'BC00563' regexp '[A-Z]' THEN 
    CONVERT(SUBSTRING("BC00563", 3, LENGTH("BC00563")), UNSIGNED) 
    ELSE 'BC00563' END;
```

You can use the column name instead of constant value.

Comment: It seems necessary because of the difference in leading zero's

Comment: @Strawberry what if we are comparing CB001 and BC002? Should CB001 not get sorted before BC002?

Comment: @Darshan Mehta interesting approach. But it's no working for me. it returns the same number of rows as if i was selecting all table

Comment: Do you have these rows in the uniform format? (i.e. 2 alphabets followed by numbers)?

Comment: @Darshan Mehta No.most of the records ar like "BC90000001", "BC90000002" and so on. But, there are some older recors where the serial number was just numbers: like "90000005". This column was the serial number stored probably as int or text, and the "BC" prefix was stripped. At some point it was changed to text and the prefix inserted. (a bad decison). And now i must find a way to select from serial x to y

Comment: @Leonida-AlexandruDiaconu updated the answer to address both the cases.